# Enabling signature verification in TeX Live 2024 (or 2023)

Tags: texlive, tlmgr, repositories, security, texlive-2024

Is it still possible to require verification of all package signatures for TeX Live? According to the documentation, I need to set the option `verify-repo` with the value `all`, but all my attempts to do this have failed.

Note that `all` is different from the default `main`. With `main`, the main repo packages are verified if `gpg` is available; otherwise, updates proceed without verification. With `all`, all repos are verified and an error is returned if `gpg` is not available. I'm particularly concerned about the second feature since I don't really use other repos, but I absolutely don't want `tlmgr` to carry on regardless if `gpg` can't be found.

```bash
cat $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFSYSCONFIG)/tlmgr/config
verify-repo = all
```

This used to work in earlier versions, though I don't seem to have got it working in TL 2023.

If I check in `tlmgr shell`, I can see the setting remains off:

```bash
$ tlmgr shell
protocol 1
tlmgr> get
Choose one of...
1) debug-translation
2) machine-readable
3) no-execute-actions
4) verify-repo
5) json
6) repository
7) prompt
> 4
verify-repo = 0
OK
tlmgr> set
Choose one of...
1) debug-translation
2) machine-readable
3) no-execute-actions
4) verify-repo
5) json
6) repository
7) prompt
> 4
Enter 1 for on, 0 for off: 1
OK
tlmgr>
```

The `1`/`0` options are themselves odd since `tlmgr`'s documentation specifies *three* (non-numerical) values `none`, `main` and `all`. These can be set either on the command line or via the configuration file and are also accessible via the shell.

In the shell, it seems I can switch verification 'on', though I'm not clear whether this means `main` or `all`. The documentation covers an older version of the shell options, I think, since the options for `get` and `set` don't correspond to those actually presented. Moreover, I don't know how to save the change. There is a `save` command, but it returns an error

```bash
tlmgr> save
Can't call method "save" on an undefined value at /usr/local/texlive/bin/tlmgr line 6889, <STDIN> line 6.
```

According to the documentation, this is intended to save the package database, so perhaps it isn't surprising it fails to save a configuration option.

I've also tried putting `1` into the configuration file. `tlmgr` then complains the value is unknown:

```bash
tlmgr shell
tlmgr: /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-config/tlmgr/config: unknown value for verify-repo: 1
protocol 1
tlmgr>
```

`get` confirms the value remains `0`.

Is it possible to enable verification in a way which persists and doesn't require remembering command line options each time?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you are trying to do. For me verifications simply works as soon as gpg is available.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If I check in `tlmgr shell`, it tells me the setting is disabled. With the default setting, `gpg` is used if available to check the main repository. This corresponds to the value `main`. I want to use the value `all`. This means `gpg` is used for all repositories (less of a concern) and an error is returned if `gpg` is not available. Only with this setting will I get an error if `gpg` isn't available for some reason. But `tlmgr shell` tells me it is disabled regardless of what I put in the config file. (This worked in 2022, but I'm not sure it worked in 2023.)